# Transparency of textures in Silverlight 5 beta (XNA)

Tags: silverlight, 3d, xna

I'm doing some experimenting with Silverlight 5 [beta] DrawingSurface

I have 2 images (PNG) with transparency in them, lets call them Im1 and Im2. The images are mapped to 2 simple polygons (6 vertices each)

When I place Im2 over Im1 I can see Im1 through the transparent parts of Im2.
When I place Im1 over Im2 I can't see Im2 and I see a black area instead of a transparent.

I'm using AlphaBlend:

```
device.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
```

And as you can guess, Im2 is drawn after Im1.

What am I doing wrong? Shader issue? Should I manually manage a Z-buffer?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308079/device-alphablend-state-in-xna-4-0/6308676#6308676).

Basically you can't use the depth-buffer with transparency. The depth buffer has no concept of "blending" - a pixel in the depth-buffer will store the topmost value - even if the *colour* of the pixel being rendered is translucent or transparent. Anything "under" the value stored in the depth-buffer is skipped.

There are two solutions to this: You can use **alpha testing** so that completely transparent pixels are not written to the depth buffer (doesn't help with translucent pixels). Or you can **sort transparent objects by depth**, so that a closer polygon never has a chance to occlude a further-away one.

You can do alpha-testing in a pixel shader or by using the `AlphaTestEffect` (if SL5 supports either of these?). Sorting polygons is something you will have to implement yourself (if you were using the full XNA, `SpriteBatch` can do this for you - but I don't think SL5 has that class).

Alternately, if depth is irrelevant and you are rendering in a back-to-front order, simply disable the depth buffer by using `DepthStencilState.None`.

Comment: Thanks, this clears up allot. I can't disable the depth buffer so I will probably have to go with alpha testing or sorting.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the transparent polygons by depth before drawing.

The code will be evaluating the colour on `Im1` first (as it's the first one in the scene) and at that point there will be nothing behind it so "show through". Then when it evaluates the colour of `Im2` it won't update `Im1`.

Sorting the polygons first will ensure that when the colour is evaluated it will have the correct background.

I'm not familiar with XNA so I can't say whether there's something built in, but when we've had to do this in the past we had to do the sorting by ourselves.