# XNA SpriteBatch ignoring my culling options?

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, sprite

I'm having a problem with the XNA SpriteBatch object.

When I draw an element that is semi-transparent in front of other elements, the other elements are hidden entirely, until the semi-transparent element is entirely transparent. This is really frustrating because I am trying to make a fade-in and fade-out effect.

> Batch.Instance.SpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Deferred, BlendState.AlphaBlend, SamplerState.LinearClamp, DepthStencilState.Default, RasterizerState.CullNone, null);

That is how I start my SpriteBatch. As you can see, I set it to CullNone, but it appears that it still does Z-culling.

How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Z-culling is a property of `DepthStencilState`. To turn it off you need to use `DepthStencilState.None`. The culling performed by `RasterizerState` is by triangle winding order. [Which I already explained to you *in detail* here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13664/what-kind-of-culling-does-xna-do-for-me).

You cannot use the depth buffer with transparency. You can use alpha-testing as a work-around for "alpha cut-outs". However for semi-transparent objects (like when they are fading in and out), drawing them in depth-order is your **only** option.

Which I've already suggested to you [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/13395/a-cool-way-of-doing-z-index-for-xna-components/13407#13407). You never answered my question there: why on earth are you drawing your GUI that way anyway?

For more information: [I've gone into more detail about transparency and the Z-buffer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308079/device-alphablend-state-in-xna-4-0).